# Testing App Clip in Testflight display 'The app clip is not currently in your country'

Tags: apple-appclips

I try to add app clip with my app,
I created an app clip target on my Xcode project and added some testing code.
For local experience, I can launch my app clip card and redirect to my app clip app successfully.

I try it for Testflight but display message 'The app clip is not currently in your country'

I upload it to Testflight. On App Store Connect, I only update the app clip section, which imports the image and subtitle and saves it.
Also, I updated my AASA file for supporting AppClip and set the associate domain on app clip target like
applinks:uat.test.com
appclips:uat.test.com

I convert https://www.test.com to QR code and scan it, the app clip card can be launched with 'The app clip is not currently in your country' message.

I want to ask if there is any setting I missed or wrong.